# Encrypting Data sent to Server

Tags: python

I would like to encrypt the data being sent from my pi to the sever. I have referenced this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287306/sending-encrypted-strings-using-socket-in-python

which seems to work, however, my question is, is it really safe if a hacker can just hack into the pi or the server and see the encryption function?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing what the encryption function is isn't particularly helpful.  The symmetric keys are what's important.  If someone manages to get access to your RPi and retrieve your keys, then no, your data is not safe. Security for the RPi (and the Python Crypto library) is really no different than it is for any other standard linux box.  So long as the RPi is properly secured, you don't need to worry.

Comment: is there a way to get around this, so that even if someone looks at the code, they can't get access to the data?

Comment: @Bruce: Like I said, the code is irrelevant.  It's the encryption keys that matter.

Comment: As Jacomb001 said, without physical security - there is no security.  Basically, once an intruder has access to the box, they can offload the keys and decrypt what ever obfuscation that you might try use - because it can not be a one way encryption, since you also need to be able to access those same keys from that RPi.   With an RPi, an intruder can even accomplish this task easier than with most systems - simply remove the sd-card and replicate it using their mobile device, place it back in the RPi - and you might not be the wiser (especially if you have no offsite logging of power-off event